# Queue CRUD Operations on localStorage for Databases

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, crud, dataflow

I need a insight or some kind of logic about my React Native app scenario.

the technology that I use are : ReactNative, Redux-Persist, MySQL, Laravel

So what I'm trying to achive is, I want my Apps to be able to handle user operations both online and offline condition. IF user is online, let say he want to create a new post then it goes straight to the database like usual. BUT when user is offline, and he create a post it will first go into some kind of temporary array on localStorage , and when he goes online there will be some functions to push the array to the database and then clear the localStorage.

Not only that, when user is trying to edit / delete some objects from the array when he is offline, it will also save the operation to the array so that they are ready to be performed as soon as user online.

I did already created all the functions to perform CRUD when the user is online , which instantly perform an operation on the databases according to user input.

Here I created a diagram to give more understanding about what I'm saying :

**When User is performing an actions :**
[image]

**When User first Open the App :**
[image]

How do I differentiate users operation whether it was and post , put or delete command ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use custom redux middleware. By naming your constants like so:

```
USER_UPDATE_POST_REQUEST
USER_UPDATE_POST_SUCCESS
USER_UPDATE_POST_FAILURE
```

then in the redux middleware you can compare the dispatch.type to see if it is a POST, PUT, DELETE.

redux middlware link:
https://redux.js.org/understanding/history-and-design/middleware